# SQL query for displaying year from date table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a table of random dates with varchar(200) data type and I am unable to generate my query of getting displayed date where year > 2000

ex:

```
12/03/2017
12/02/1998
12/11/2002
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `varchar(200)`?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: it is beign specified in question to enter date in varchar

Comment: **Never** ever store dates as VARCHAR

Comment: Since you are storing strings, you should also add to your question the format you use.,

Comment: sql  server 2008 pro

Comment: use examples that make it clear which is the month and which is the day.

Comment: Do you have multiple dates stored in one column?

Comment: @UtpalAwasthi . . . Just because a use *inputs* a date as a string does not mean that it should be stored that way.  In fact, if the data is coming from user inputs, you specifically want to convert to a date to ensure that the value is valid.

Comment: So a valid 200 character date could be "The Ides of March in the Year of Their Lord 666", "next Rosh Hashanah" or "Frabjous Day, 42 B.C.E."? Should the year always correspond to the calendar at hand, be it Tamil or something else? Is there a reason you don't support Unicode dates?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be storing dates as strings.  It is a bad idea to store fields in the wrong type.

Second, if you do have to store dates as strings (which is occasionally necessary), then use the ISO standard formats:  YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.

For the format that you are using, you can extract the last four characters:

```
select right(DateWronglyStoredInStringColumn, 4) as yyyy
```

Comment: Agreed. I have a system that has to have plain text dates reported to it, and we store them like that (I was not the DBA that set up the system). For my queries, I typically convert the text to a date format, manipulate it, then display it in another more easily readable plain text format. It's a pain, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing your dates as a `date` or `datetime2` or `datetime` datatype in sql server.

For sql server versions prior to sql server 2012, try just using [**`convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

For dates where the day is first, use [**`set dateformat`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)`dmy;`

```
set dateformat dmy;
select 
    year(convert(date,randomDate)) as [Year]
  , randomDate
from t
where year(convert(date,randomDate)) > 2000;
```

For sql server 2012+, you could use [**`try_convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx):

```
set dateformat dmy;
select 
    year(try_convert(date,randomDate)) as [Year]
  , randomDate
from t
where year(try_convert(date,randomDate)) > 2000;
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DXVR82331

```
create table a ( date varchar(200) );
insert into a values
 ('13-09-2017')
,('12-12-1987')
,('27-01-2037')
,('22-04-1877')
,('02-11-1987')
,('16-08-1974');

set dateformat dmy;
select convert(date,a.[date]) as date
from a
where year(convert(date,a.[date])) > 2000;
```

returns:

```
+---------------------+
|        date         |
+---------------------+
| 13.09.2017 00:00:00 |
| 27.01.2037 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @UtpalAwasthi You're going to have to post some sample data with text format of how you are storing your dates. This is why you shouldn't store them as `varchar()` in the first place :\

Comment: use utpal
create table a
(
date varchar(200),
)
select * from a
insert into a values('13-09-2017');
insert into a values('12-12-1987');
insert into a values('27-01-2037');
insert into a values('22-04-1877');
insert into a values('02-11-1987');
insert into a values('16-08-1974');

Comment: @UtpalAwasthi `set dateformat dmy;` before your query: demo: http://rextester.com/DXVR82331

Comment: it is showing this error-Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @UtpalAwasthi use `convert()`

Answer (score 0):

Try 
select date 
from a where convert(char(4),date,121) > '2000'
But be careful when you sort or order the year as You use varchar (text).
Might want to convert the year to an integer for that purpose.